# condition with the shortcode array variable

Tags: wordpress

I have this code for displaying shortcode.

```
<?php function img($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'source' => '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/noimage.jpg" />',
      'style' => 'online'

   ), $atts));

return '<div class="box extend box1" style="here is the conditional if statement, if the style variable is equal to online then output the background: url(images/online.jpg) else if the style variable is equal to notonline then output background: url(images/notonline.jpg)">'.$source.'</div>';
}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('img', 'img');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

?>

no what im trying to achieve was here is the conditional if statement, if the style variable is equal to online then output the background: url(images/online.jpg) else if the style variable is equal to notonline then output background: url(images/notonline.jpg), could someone share atleast of an idea how to achieve that? currently im looking for the approach of my objective but unfortunately, no result yet.

Im open in suggestions, recommendations and ideas. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php function img($atts) {
    $source = $atts['source'];
    $style = $atts['style'];
    $ret .= '<div class="box extend box1" style="background: url(images/';
    if('online' == $style){
        $ret .= 'online.jpg';
    }else{
        $ret .= 'notonline.jpg';
    }
    $ret .= ');">'.$source.'</div>';
    return $ret;
}
...
?>
```

should work for what you want, `extract( shortcode_atts(...))` is overkill

Comment: what? either way is fine, i just figured this would make things more transparent.  `$atts` is just an array of key-pair values based on what is passed into the shortcode.  `$atts` and the key-pairs can be used just like any other variable

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of [`if/else`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). Note that you don't need to attach the [Shortcode declaration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to the `init` action. Also, always prefix your function names to avoid conflicts with other plugins.

```
function my_img($atts) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'source' => '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/noimage.jpg" />',
      'style' => 'online'

   ), $atts));

   if( $style == 'online' )
       $bg = 'background: url(images/online.jpg)';
   else
       $bg = 'background: url(images/notonline.jpg)';

   return '<div class="box extend box1" style="'.$bg.'">'.$source.'</div>';
}

add_shortcode('img', 'my_img');
```